# Strange behavior of jQuery code in the href attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I saw that it's possible place jquery code in the `href` attribute of the html `a` tag.

That code, however, works so I do not understand: it works after the second click.
Why?

```html
<a href="javascript:alert('ok JavaScript')">JS</a>
<br>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<a id="myId" href='javascript:
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myId").click(function() {
      alert("ok jQuery");
    });
  });'>jQ</a>
```

Comment: While it's possible to add JS code in the `href`, you *really, really* shouldn't

Comment: @Rory, I need a bookmarklet that would use just me...

Comment: Document ready function called once when the dom is ready to execute js codes. In your code, you are clicking and executing your javascript manually, so first it's calling document ready function, waiting for myId click function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing strange in this behavior.
There are no jQuery `click` handlers bound to your link at the beginning.

However, when you click it at the first time, it executes the following script from its `href`:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("#myId").click(function() {
    alert("ok jQuery");
  });
});
```

and binds a handler to your link.
So, after the first click you have no `alert`, but you now have a `click` handler bound to your `#myId`.

When you click it at the second time, it fires fresh-bound jQuery event, which shows the alert.
Also, it executes `href` again, so when you click this link again, you will get two (the same) click handlers and two alerts, and number of alerts will be incremented each time.

Answer (score 2):

In the first click, the function in href attribute gets executed and the handler gets bound to the 'myId' anchor element. In the second click handler gets executed and it shows alert.

Answer (score 1):

The first click defines the click event to show the alert box.

The second click executes the code and show the alert box.

As the comment, you shouldn't include this code into the href attribute since that's a bad practice.